# Python -- Morse Code Translation through a binary tree

Tags: python, binary-search-tree, morse-code

I'm writing a program that will create a binary tree of the Morse Code alphabet (as well as a period and an apostrophe), and which will then read a line of Morse Code and translate it into English. (Yes, I know that a look-up table would be easier, but I need to sort out my binary trees). I think a good bit of my problem is that I want to put the values into the tree in alphabetical order, rather than by symbol order. But surely there must be a way to do that? Because if I had a million such values that weren't numeric, I wouldn't need to sort them into the simplest order for insertion...right?

It's reading from a text file where each line has one sentence in Morse Code.
- .... .. ...  .. ...  ..-. ..- -. .-.-.-   for example, which is "This is fun."
1 space between symbols means it's a new letter, 2 spaces means it's a new word.

As it stands, I'm getting the output  ".$$$" for that line given above, which means it's reading a period and then getting an error which is symbolized by ('$$$'), which is obviously wrong...

Like I said before, I know I'm being complicated, but surely there's a way to do this without sorting the values in my tree first, and I'd like to figure this out now, rather than when I'm in a time crunch.

Does anyone have any insight? Is this something so horribly obvious that I should be embarrassed for asking about it?

Comment: Morse is already a binary tree structure start with e and t dot is left dash is right. It was designed this way. A lookup in a dictionary also works.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to SO and thanks for an interesting question. Yes, it looks to me like you're overcomplicating things a bit. For example, there's absolutely no need to use classes here. You can reuse existing python data structures to represent a tree:

```
def add(node, value, code):
    if code:
        add(node.setdefault(code[0], {}), value, code[1:])
    else:
        node['value'] = value

tree = {}
for value, code in alphabet:
    add(tree, value, code)

import pprint; pprint.pprint(tree)
```

This gives you a nested dict with keys `.`, `-`, and `value` which will be easier to work with.

Comment: Thanks!
But I've already figured out how to do this sort of thing with a dictionary. I'm now doing it with a linked list of sorts to learn, and I can't see why it doesn't work with links like this...Is there some inherent flaw with linked "whatsits" that I don't know about, or is it my implementation that's off?
I've figured out linked lists and how to insert some value into the middle of them without getting everything jumbled, so I don't understand why I'm having such a problem with  something that seems pretty similar to me...
Any more tips? Or should I abandon this method completely?

Comment: @user2309856: personally I don't think studying "linked lists" and other low-level data structures has any practical value. In a high-level language this kind of stuff is already given to you. My advice: learn how to write good idiomatic python on simple but real problems. For example, your morse code decoder - as you correctly pointed out, a lookup table is the best way and will require no more than 5 lines of code. Problem solved, up to the next one.